# Backbone not calling the router function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I have the following backbone route:

```
Nightbird.Routers.Errors = Nightbird.Routers.Core.extend({

  routes: {
    'server_error': 'serverError',
  },

  initialize: function(){
    console.log('dasddasd');
  },

  serverError: function() {
    console.log('asdasdasd');
    var serverErrorView = new Nightbird.Views.ServerError();
    serverErrorView.render();
  }
});
```

it does come into this class because the `initialize` function is being called, when this route loads I see: `dasddasd` in the console, but I do no see `asdasdasd`

The url is `localhost:9000/#server_error`

Can some one explain what I am doing wrong? I am not sure what else I am suppose to provide for further information so please ask for any additional details.

## Additional

The following is how the app gets registered:

```
window.Nightbird = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},

  blogId: 0,

  initialize: function() {
    if (window.Development === undefined && window.Production === undefined) {
      throw 'Production class (Production.config.js) cannot be missing. App Cannot load.';
    }

    if (window.Development !== undefined) {
      this.blogId = window.Development.BLOG_ID;
    } else {
      this.blogId = window.Production.BLOG_ID;
    }

    new Nightbird.Routers.Posts();
    new Nightbird.Routers.Errors();

    if (!Backbone.History.started) {
      Backbone.history.start();
    } else {
      Backbone.history.stop();
      Backbone.history.start();
    }
  }
}
```

This class extends:

```
Nightbird.Routers.Core = Backbone.Router.extend({

  serverError: function(){
    Backbone.history.navigate("server_error", {trigger: true});
  }

});
```

Why such a simple abstraction, because this way any issue getting or posting or what have you can redirect you to a server error route.

Then in my `index.html` I do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="manage">
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/compiled.js"></script>
  <script>
    Nightbird.initialize();
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Dou you have this code: ````Backbone.history.start()```` ?

Comment: @SlawaEremkin I updated the post  - and yes I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem is the way that you're instantiating the Backbone Router
Try to create the Backbone Router inheriting from Backbone.Router.

When you check if Backbone.History.started is true, it probably is not. so it will go to else statement, and there at that moment Backbone.History.star() is undefined. So it is never starting the Backbone.History

Hope it helps.

Comment: What I don't understand is why I cannot define my own custom core router that extends from Backbone - well maybe its not a case of cant, its more of a case of - why is this extension an issue?

Comment: window.Nightbird is a simple hash. It is not inheriting from backbone view or backbone model or backbone router...

Comment: You are right its not but in the case of `Nightbird.Routers.Core` it does extend from `Backbone.Router`

So the chain of inheritance is just extended by one. I can show you that code too if that will help :D

Comment: So, Nightbird.Routers.Core is extending from Bakcbone Router.. OK  but Nightbird.Routers.Errors is not... Try to meke Nightbird.Routers extend from backbone router

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60252/discussion-between-rcarvalho-and-user3379926).